# Gallery like flickr. Photo on the full width the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

Please advise gallery like flickr, I mean when pressing button http://prntscr.com/9qx9xx It is necessary to make it work with Ajax. Are there any ready-made solutions? I would be very grateful.